# Oracle APEX: Server 404 - no jQuery or images are loaded

Tags: oracle-apex

[image: Chrome Developer]

From one to another my images are not displayed anymore. I looked the path and it is still the same like before and I didnt change the path in APEX.
I looked in the Chrome Console and saw that also jQuery won't load anymore.

Did someone faced the same? I guess it is a path error but I didnt change anything and only in one application it's not working.

**APEX 18.1**

Answer (score 1):

Try to update the Images directory.

I don't have Apex 18, but in previous versions it was done as follows:

- connect to the database as SYS (as SYSDBA)
- run the apxldimg file, such as this:

---

```
SQL> @apxldimg C:\apex_installation_folder
```

where `C:\apex_installation_folder` represents a folder you extracted installation files to.